# How to write ^ in LaTeX?

Tags: text

I would like to type a^b in LaTeX. Note that I do not want b as superscript for a in the sense a power b, rather I want the text as is.

I have seen here (http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_155.html) that `^` is a special character and can be written as `\^`.

However, `a\^b` yields 'a', followed by b with a hat. Somewhat like `$\hat{b}$`.

I have tried `\^` to print the ^ character alone, ie., not followed by any text or numbers before or after. I get the following error:

"`Missing \endcsname inserted. \end`"

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try \^{} instead. Should work

Comment: @JairoADelRio: Your suggestion works. a\^{}b solves my issue. I will accept once you post an answer.

Comment: I've added some more explanation, just in case :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Easy solution (recommended)

Use `\^{}`

```
a\^{}b
```

### Using catcodes (risky)

You can make `^` a letter changing its catcode to 12, but superscripts in math mode won't work

```
\documentclass{article}
%The superscript sign is just a letter from now on
\catcode`\^=12
\begin{document}
^ 
%Try $x^2$
\end{document}
```

### Using catcodes (another way)

Another possibility is make `^` an active character, i.e., *grosso modo*, make it work like another macro. Since LaTeX defines `\sp` as a replacement of `^`, no worries here

```
\documentclass{article}
%We make ^ active
\catcode`\^=13
%We define ^ so it works only in math mode
\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi }
\begin{document}
I can use ^ finally %works

$x^2$ %works too
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure about the way LaTeX handles with catcodes (I like LuaTeX/ConTeXt catcode tables better), so maybe you'll break things with larger documents. I'm pretty sure that you should go for the easy way. :)

Answer (score 5):

The LaTeX kernel provides `\textasciicircum` for the job.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\oti}{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont} % shorthand

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
OT1 & T1 \\
\hline
\oti a\^{}b & a\^{}b \\
\oti a\textasciicircum b & a\textasciicircum b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd prefer the output with the T1 encoding.

The left column is used just to show that with OT1 (the default encoding) you get the same result from `\textasciicircum` and `\^{}`.

*Caveat*. Anyway, one has to check the output, because some fonts may have a disputable glyph for `\textasciicircum` in T1 encoding.

Comment: @user187802 That font surely has a very badly designed glyph. `:-(` I added a *caveat*.

Answer (score 1):

Without advocating for any method over just`\^{}`, for the shake of completeness, as `a^b` seems of little use un plain text, probably instead of the canonical way to avoid take "b" as argument, one may want a verbatim mode or math mode here, using another another way. The next example compare ten methods to type circumflex-like symbols in verbatim, math mode or plain text mode with pdflatex, producing four different symbols:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}\obeylines
1\tab   \verb|a^b|              
2\tab   $a^{\wedge}b$           
3\tab   $a^{\land}b$            
4\tab   $a\mathop{\hat{}}b$     
5\tab   $a\mbox{\^{}}b$
6\tab   a$^\wedge$b
7\tab   a\^{}b                  
8\tab   aˆb  
9\tab   a\detokenize{^}b        
10\tab  a\textasciicircum b     
\end{document}

% Note:  circumflex accent in line 8 is U+02C6, not U+005E
```

Comment: Very nice also your answer....my best regards.